# how to include mobile like scrollbars in AngularJS based web application?

Tags: facebook, angularjs, user-interface

I've a web application based on AngularJS which runs on mobile phone. I've screens that have scrollbars. But I want these scrollbars to look like a standard mobile scrollbars.

For example, see the scrollbars used inside facebook.com. Iam looking for scrolbars like these.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an awesome JavaScript lib that does all more than scroll and because their modules are broken up functionally, developers only need to use the one that fits their need thereby reducing the net time.

It works on mobile and across platforms as well.

No dependency on any other library as well (like jQuery or AngularJS).

Check this out [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/).

Appreciations to iScroll team !

Answer (score 1):

Try [ng-scrollbar](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar) which is pure AngularJS coded.

> Tired of using jquery for a stupid scrollbar? well, this directive is
>   just for you.
>
> A custom scrollbar written in pure AngularJS.

Comment: Thanks @Gromo, this is a wonderful option, I was able to see this on mobile browser, but I could not scroll the area in mobile device. :( Can you please suggest a solution? Your help is really appreciated. Thanks again :)

Comment: I didn't work with this plugin, but, as I can see from its source code and by behavior, it does not support mobile touch events. It works only with mouse wheel events. For mobile devices you can use [custom scrollbars with pure CSS](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) - it will work with mobile chrome and safari (most of android/apple devices).

Comment: Really impressive scrollbars. Unfortunately, works only with webkit based browsers :( . So, it wont work with FireFox or Windows platforms dont know about blackberry. I really really wish if all the browsers had this feature. This is infact a thing to be done via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: Slimscroll JQuery plugin:
http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll

Comment: Thanks, BUT im not using jQuery, I am only using AngularJS and I am looking for an option that is not based on jQuery.

Comment: You could have a look at slimScrolls code and translate that to angular's jqLite. But looking at the amount of dom manipulation, I think it would be easier using jQuery.

Comment: Yes. Or else is there a javascript based library (which is **NOT** based on jQuery or any other library) that does this?

Comment: @TempOrary Why not jQuery-based solution? Angular works perfectly with jQuery, and even more - Angular uses jQuery for DOM objects if it's included. Maybe you do not want to use `$(document).ready` or `$(window).load`, don't you? If so, you can try jQuery plugins that integrated with Angular as directive, for example [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/).

Comment: Thanks @Gromo, I checked this in my android mobile web browser. But it did not work. I could not see the scrollbars. So, this will not work. Request you to suggest another solution that will work on mobile/tablet and desktop devices consistently.

Comment: @TempOrary forgot to tell you to set option `ignoreMobile` to `false`, as by default mobile browser looks pretty good and custom scrollbar is not initialized on mobile devices.

Comment: @Gromo, I found a great tool for this. Please check this out.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @TempOrary I saw this plugin too - it looks cool. But you've asked scrollbar for angular, and I've tried to help you with this :)